# Extracting a node from Json File in C#

Tags: c#, json

In the JSON File, I would like to extract the data from the node. Say like I wanted to extract the book node or value which is within goods node. Here is my JSON file.

**JSON**

```
    {  
   "store":[  
      {  
         "name":"Sunshine Department Store",
         "address":"Wangfujing Street",
         "goods":{  
            "book":[  
               {  
                  "category":"Reference",
                  "title":"Sayings of the Century",
                  "author":"Nigel Rees",
                  "price":8.88
               },
               {  
                  "category":"Fiction",
                  "title":"Sword of Honour",
                  "author":"Evelyn Waugh",
                  "price":12.66
               }
            ],
            "bicycle":{  
               "type":"GIANT OCR2600",
               "color":"White",
               "price":276
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Code**

```
private string ParseBookNode(JObject bookJSONFile)
{
    JArray bookJson = null;
    string bookFarmNode = null;
    if (bookJSONFile != null && bookJSONFile["store"] != null)
    {
        bookJson = (JArray)bookJSONFile["store"];
        bookFarmNode = bookJson[0].ToString();

        if (bookJSONFile["book"] != null)
        {
            bookJson = (JArray)bookJSONFile["book"];
            bookFarmNode = bookJson[0].ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Book node not found.");
    }
    return bookFarmNode;
}
```

How can I extract data along these lines??

```
if (bookJSONFile["book"] != null)
{
    bookJson = (JArray)bookJSONFile["book"];
    bookFarmNode = bookJson[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: `bookJSONFile["book"]` will never exist. Did you mean to look in `bookFarmNode` instead? In which case you'd then have to drill into the "goods" object first as well. Check the structure of your JSON, and which variables you're using, more carefully. Giving your variables more meaningful names would probably help you organise your code.

Comment: Yes Dyson, My Mistake it is bookJson["book"].

Comment: That won't exist either. Look again at your data structure. bookJSON will be the "store" array (hence why I said, you have unhelpful variable names). bookFarmNode (if you make it an object instead of a string) will be the first object from that array. Then you have to get the "goods" object from within that, and then get the book array from within the the "goods" object.

Answer (score 2):

You can access this with Json.Net.

I just added look up by category just to show you that you can do things like this.

```
    public static JObject GetBook(JObject jObject, string category)
    {
        JObject returnValue = null;
        try
        {
            var array = jObject.Property("store").Value;
            var first = (JObject)array.FirstOrDefault();

            var goods = first?.Property("goods").Value;

            var books = ((JObject)goods).Property("book").Value;

            var booksArray = books as JArray;

            foreach (JObject book in booksArray)
            {
                if (book.Property("category")?.Value?.ToString() == category)
                {
                    returnValue = book;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code bears little relation to your data structure, and your variable names are confusing, which probably isn't helping you organise the code properly.

This (untested I'm afraid) should get you as far as accessing the book array (in the first object of the "store" array), I think.

```
private string ParseBookNode(JObject bookJSONFile)
{
    JArray storeList = null;
    JObject store = null;
    JObject goods = null;
    JArray bookList = null;

    if (bookJSONFile != null && bookJSONFile["store"] != null)
    {
        storeList = (JArray)bookJSONFile["store"];
        store = bookJson[0];
        goods = store["goods"];

        if (goods["book"] != null)
        {
            bookList = (JArray)goods["book"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("File is empty, or Store node not found.");
    }
    return "something, not sure what you want to return here";
}
```

Apologies for any mistakes, but hopefully you get the general idea. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm has comprehensive documentation as well on how to use JArray and JObject.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library to parsing / writing JSON files. Here is how you can parse and load book nodes

```
using (var jr = new ChoJSONReader("sample9.json").WithJSONPath("$..book")
    )
{
    foreach (var x in jr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Category: {x.category}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Title: {x.title}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Author: {x.author}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Price: {x.price}");
    }
}
```

If you have POCO book type defined as below

```
public class Book
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

You can load them as below

```
using (var jr = new ChoJSONReader<Book>("sample9.json").WithJSONPath("$..book")
)
{
    foreach (var x in jr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Category: {x.Category}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Title: {x.Title}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Author: {x.Author}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Price: {x.Price}");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.